# Search only specific object parameters in typeahead

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular typeahead for searching users. I have array which include `empId`, `empName`, `imageUrl`, `skills`. In that I want to search by only `empName` & `skills` parameters. But currently result is filtering `imageUrl` also. I want filter for only `empName` & `skills`.

Below is my code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search people here..." 
  ng-change="getMatchedUser();"  ng-model="selected" 
  data-typeahead="user as user.name for user in searchMembers | filter:$viewValue" 
  typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" 
  typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"  />
```

My search array is below

```
$scope.searchMembers = [
                {
                 "empName":"abc",
                 "imageUrl":"default.jpg",
                 "skills": "java"
                },
                {
                 "empName":"pqr",
                 "imageUrl":"default.jpg",
                 "skills": "php"
                }
               ];
```

Comment: write a filter that  returns mapped array with only the desired properties

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a filter function of your own then. Something like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search people here..." ng-change="getMatchedUser();"  ng-model="selected" data-typeahead="user as user.name for user in getMatchingUsers($viewValue)" typeahead-wait-ms=100  typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"  />
```

In controller,

```
$scope.getMatchingUsers=function($viewValue){
    var matchingUsers = [];
    for (var i=0; i< $scope.searchMembers.length; i++) {
      if (
        $scope.searchMembers[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf($viewValue.toLowerCase()) != -1 ||
        $scope.searchMembers[i].skills.toLowerCase().indexOf($viewValue.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {
        matchingUsers.push($scope.searchMembers[i]);      
      }
    }
    return matchingUsers;
}
```

Comment: hii.. but i want to search by skills also.. above code only gives search result filter by names..

Comment: Thank a lot... Nijeesh

Comment: one another problem is here with ng-change, that is on keypress first time search result list is not display , after second click it shows search result list.. is it problem of usiong ng-change in typeahead ? i want every time filtered record . so i used ng-change &  getMatchedUser() function return every time only matched result. is it right way ???

Comment: Its possible that ng-change gets called before ng-model value is set. Try adding a typeahead-wait-ms attribute to input. I have edited the ans with wait

Comment: And please mark answer correct if u found it useful :)

Comment: Hii. Nijeesh, thanks.. Filter is work properly.. but on first keypress till search list is not display.. in console in getMatchedUser(),  i get all filter results but it will not display, after second key press result is display.. what should i do in this case ?